# How do I remove a file reference in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

This is an odd one.  I added a file to a project, thought I didn't need it so deleted, then realized I did indeed need it.  When deleting I was prompted for whether to move to trash or just remove references, I chose remove reference.  Now I can't add that file back in because I'm told there's already a file there by that name.  What's going on here?  There is no file by that name in the project listing.  Is there some other place I need to go to remove something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only removed the reference to the file, then it is still located in the project folder and you can't add a new file with the same name. So you should go to the folder where your project is located, and delete the file. (Right click on the project and select **Show in Finder**)